# PHP: Executing Command Line Application That Prompts Users

Tags: php, command-line, lamp, wamp

I have a command line application I need to execute from my PHP web application. Say the command is the following:

```
foo -arg1 -arg2 -arg3
```

Based on certain conditions, the command line application will prompt user to hit the enter key (e.g. "Please press enter to continue.").

From my PHP application, how do I execute the command line AND send the enter key as response to the prompt?

I'm developing on WAMP. Production code is LAMP.

Comment: Sometimes CLI programs have a batch mode option which tells them to not ask questions, if one of these options is available you should use it. If it is your own program, you could consider adding an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the 'yes' program is for.  It dumps an endless stream of 'y\n' (or whatever you tell it to via arguments) to the program.  It exists for this purpose (answering 'yes' to "do you want to continue" prompts).

```
shell_exec('yes | foo -arg1 -arg2 -arg3')
```

Answer (score 1):

You will really need to o[pen a process handle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and parse the programs output and write appropriate output in response.

Check out the [expect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/expect.examples-usage.php) extension though, which can make this sort of thing easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
$value = fgets(STDIN);
```

This will allow the user to enter in a value, which you can then access via $value.

Comment: From the question, it seems that the php script is not running from the command-line...

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried `echo "\n" > foo -arg1 -arg2 -arg3` ?

Comment: No, I have not. How do I execute such a command from a web application such that it knows I am trying to run a command line? I usually use exec(). You have echo(), which displays output to the browser.

Comment: no, that would've been `shell_exec('echo "\n" > ...')`, i just omitted the php exec code for brevity. I think it needs to be `shell_exec('foo -arg1... | echo "\n"')` though come to think of it.

Comment: It should be 'echo "\n" | foo ...'

Comment: hmm, tested with echo "q" to less /var/log/some_log and it looked like it worked but ofcoarse, it wrote a file named "less" instead of actually running less. oh well